# Is this piece of code thread safe?

Tags: java, executorservice

```
private static final Word2Vec word2vectors = getWordVector();

    private static Word2Vec getWordVector() {
        String PATH;
        try {
            PATH = new ClassPathResource("models/word2vec_model").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        log.warn("Loading model...");
        return WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel(new File(PATH));
    }

        ExecutorService pools = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Future<?>> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
        if (word2vectors != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
                MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable("beautiful", i);
                runnables.add(pools.submit(runnable));
            }
        }
        for(Future<?> task: runnables){
            try {
                task.get();
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }catch(ExecutionException ee){
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        pools.shutdown();

static class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
        private String word;
        private int count;
        public MyRunnable(String word, int i){
            this.word = word;
            this.count = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                Collection<String> words = word2vectors.wordsNearest(word, 5);
                log.info("Top 5 cloest words: " + words);
                log.info(String.valueOf(count));
        }
    }
```

The word2vectors.wordsNearest() is a method from a public library. I intend to let 4 threads to concurrently execute the method to speed up the process. Is this thread safe?

Comment: Depends on the `wordsNearest` method.

Comment: If i can't control wordsNearest, how can I make this code safe?

Comment: Without knowing anything else the only safe way is to use one thread or synchronize on `word2vectors` when you call `wordsNearest`.

Comment: And if you at least know it doesn't use static fields (or mutable global variables in general), then you can create 4 instances of whatever type `word2vectors` is. I would say that's a fairly low bar to pass, any sane library should be able to do it.

Comment: Since you are only submitting one Runnable to the ExecutorService you will only be running one thread. Definitely thread safe but you probaly meant to have 4 threads running the task.

Comment: @bhspencer Nice, I was sure there is a loop for some reason.

Comment: If you want to run 4 threads concurrently you need to submit 4 tasks. In that case no not thread safe. You probably want to give each Runnable a portion of the 1000000 each. In short your code is thread safe bit is is completely broken and wont do what you think it does.

Comment: @bhspencer, why isn't the code run concurrently with 4 threads? In the pool it has 4 threads.

Comment: @user697911 - See my answer for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet will be thread-safe if the following conditions are met:

1. The `word2vectors.wordsNearest(...)` call is thread-safe
2. The `word2vectors` data structure is created and initialized by the current thread.
3. Nothing changes the data structure between the pools.execute call and the computation finishing.

If `wordsNearest` doesn't look at other data structures, and if it doesn't change the `word2vectors` data structure, then it is a *reasonable assumption* that it is thread-safe.  However, the only way to be sure is to *analyse it*.

But it is also worth noting that you are only submitting a single task to the executor.  Since each task is work to be run by a single thread, your code effectively uses only one thread.  To exploit multi-threading you need to split your single big task into multiple small and independent tasks; e.g. put the 10,000 repetitions loop outside of the execute call ...

Comment: can you take this as an example and split it into multiple small tasks?

Comment: I have already told you one way to do it.  Read my answer again.

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion. It seems working unsafely. Suppose I have no control of word2vectors.wordsNearest, how can I make this method thread safe?

Comment: If you do not know that `wordsNearest` is thread-safe, then the **ONLY** way to guarantee thread safety is to only use one thread.

Comment: @StephenC Or use synchronization.

Comment: @Oleg - That won't necessarily help.  It won't help if the Word2Vec is being updated behind the scenes; e.g. by some other thread that he **cannot** synchronize with.  Bear in mind the OP has said he "cannot control" it.